# Eliminar filas en un DataFrame, de acuerdo con un criterio preestablecido

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

El script siguiente, pretendo que lea, uno a uno, los valores en la columna 'Position, y los compare  con el valor en la fila anterior en la misma columna. Si ambos son iguales, debo eliminar la fila que estoy leyendo en ese momento, de tal manera que, como producto final, obtenga un DataFrame que en la columna 'Position' tenga 1, 0, 1, 0... consecutivamente..

```
from datetime import datetime       
import pandas as pd

Date = ['2018-02-06 ' , '2018-06-29 ', '2019-07-09 ', '2020-03-16 ', '2020-08-24',  '2020-12-03',  '2020-12-15','2021-01-08 ' ,                     '2021-01-27 ','2021-04-16 ']
Close = [150.61, 160.08, 178.17, 140.35, 189.4, 200.6, 202.46, 209.26, 207.54, 230.39] 
Position = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 ]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Date, Close, Position)), columns =['Date', 'Close', 'Position']) 

for i in range (1, len(df)):
    if df.loc[i-1,'Position'] == 1:
        df.drop([i],axis=0)
    elif df.loc[i-1,'Position'] == 0:
        df.drop([i],axis=0)
```

que devuelve el DataFrame

```
    Date    Close   Position
0   2018-02-06  150.61  1
1   2018-06-29  160.08  0
2   2019-07-09  178.17  0
3   2020-03-16  140.35  1
4   2020-08-24  189.40  1
5   2020-12-03  200.60  1
6   2020-12-15  202.46  0
7   2021-01-08  209.26  0
8   2021-01-27  207.54  1
9   2021-04-16  230.39  1
```

Viendo la salida del script, es evidente que no lo hace.
Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes primero comparar si el valor de "Position" en la fila es igual al de la fila anterior utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) y luego utilizar el inverso de esa comparación para filtrar

Para comparar si el valor es igual al de la fila anterior utilizamos:

```
df['Position'] == df['Position'].shift()
```

Y luego únicamente utilizamos el inverso de ese comparación para el filtro

```
df[~(df['Position'] == df['Position'].shift())]
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

Date = ['2018-02-06' , '2018-06-29', '2019-07-09', '2020-03-16', '2020-08-24',  '2020-12-03', '2020-12-15', '2021-01-08' , '2021-01-27','2021-04-16']
Close = [150.61, 160.08, 178.17, 140.35, 189.4, 200.6, 202.46, 209.26, 207.54, 230.39] 
Position = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 ]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Date, Close, Position)), columns =['Date', 'Close', 'Position'])
print(df[~(df['Position'] == df['Position'].shift())])
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    Date        Close   Position
0   2018-02-06  150.61  1
1   2018-06-29  160.08  0
3   2020-03-16  140.35  1
6   2020-12-15  202.46  0
8   2021-01-27  207.54  1
```

Si deseas reacomodar los índices puedes utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
print(df[~(df['Position'] == df['Position'].shift())].reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
    Date        Close   Position
0   2018-02-06  150.61  1
1   2018-06-29  160.08  0
2   2020-03-16  140.35  1
3   2020-12-15  202.46  0
4   2021-01-27  207.54  1
```

Comment: Gracias Heytale. Solución pytonisa. Hay funciones que todavía no he interiorizado suficientemente como para que, me vengan a la cabeza de forma natural cuando tropiezo con un problema. Es el caso de 'shift', que solo me acordaba de ella para calcular desviaciones y pordentajes.

Comment: No hay de qué, saludos!